# Notice for object conversion

Tags: php

I'm doing a search engine for eBay-API, though I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, I get the error of:

> **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object** in D:\xamp\htdocs\webapp\queries.php on line 431

Line `431` is:

```
if ($darkarteli->Item->SellingStatus->CurrentPrice <= 10 && $darkarteli->Item->SellingStatus->CurrentPrice >= 25 && $darkarteli->ListingType == 'FixedPriceItem')
```

Full code snippet:

```
foreach ($temparrrayforproducts as $darkartelis){
    global $itemidsfromgetsellerlist;
    $nd=[];
    array_push($nd, $darkartelis->ItemArray);
    foreach($nd as $darkartelis->Item){
        if ($darkarteli->Item->SellingStatus->CurrentPrice <= 10 && $darkarteli->Item->SellingStatus->CurrentPrice >= 25 && $darkarteli->ListingType == 'FixedPriceItem'){
            array_push($itemidsfromgetsellerlist, $darkarteli->Item->ItemID);
        }
    }
}

var_dump ($itemidsfromgetsellerlist);
```

Beautified `var_dump()` for `$darkartelis`: https://pastebin.com/xi34Vzn7

**EDIT:** I tried this code and it doesn't give out any errors, but it doesn't pass through the if statement even though there are 10-25 priced items which are fixedpriceitems also

```
foreach($temparrrayforproducts as $ndd){//pro kiekviena getsellerlist
    global $itemidsfromgetsellerlist;
    $nd=[];
    array_push($nd, $ndd->ItemArray->Item); // tada per get seller list item arr
    foreach($nd as $k=>$nds){ // per kiekviena itema
        if (is_object($nds)&&!empty($nds)){
            if ($nds->SellingStatus->CurrentPrice <= 10.00 && $nds->SellingStatus->CurrentPrice >= 25.00 && $nds->ListingType == 'FixedPriceItem'){
                echo "Hallelujah";
                array_push($itemidsfromgetsellerlist, $nds->ItemID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you shift from `$darkartelis` to `$darkarteli`, would be my guess...

Comment: changed it, same thing

Comment: Hm. Haven't looked too much at the content, but it seems you might be using the wrong syntax. First, you create a new array, and push the content of `$darkartelis->ItemArray` into that. Then you split that array with `$nd as $darkartelis->Item` - but you're missing a step. There is no `->Item->SellingStatus` - it would be `->Item->0->SellingStatus` - you're missing the iterator between `Item` and `SellingStatus`

Comment: I don't know, don't know how to implement it